# Opening the imidazoline ring in tolazoline

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, synthesis, chemical-biology

[image]

Hello.
I was studying about the alkaline ring opening or purines. While doing research, i came across this compound. This got me thinking if we can use the same procedure to open the imidazoline ring in tolazoline.
Please give me as much information as possible about the reaction and reagents that will be used in opening the imidazoline ring of tolazoline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compound you have drawn is an imidazoline not an imidazole - big difference.

Imidazolines are fairly easily to hydroyse in both acidic and basic media, there is a good review [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02541864).

Imidazoles on the other hand are much more stable aromatic compounds and the hydrolytic ring opening is far from straighforward.